# Having trouble running a command from Robot Framework using BuiltIn and Process Library

Tags: automation, automated-tests, accessibility, robotframework

so I am using Windows 7. There is a command that I am running from the command prompt: node sample2.js => results.csv. 
And it works great, it writes the results to the csv. But, when i try to run it from Robot Framework using:

```
Test node sample
    ${command}=    Set Variable    node ${path}\\sample2.js => results.csv
    Run    ${command}
```

It runs the file and passes in Robot Framework and it creates a csv file, however the csv file is blank.
Anyone know how to solve this?
Here is the sample2.js code if that helps:

```
var AxeBuilder = require('axe-webdriverjs'),
    AxeReports = require('axe-reports'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome') //or firefox or whichever driver you use
    .build();

var AXE_BUILDER = AxeBuilder(driver)
    .withTags(['wcag2a', 'wcag2aa']); // specify your test criteria (see aXe documentation for more info)

AxeReports.createCsvReportHeaderRow();
driver.get('https://www.google.com');
driver.wait(until.titleIs('Google'), 10000)
    .then(function () {
        AXE_BUILDER.analyze(function (results) {
            AxeReports.createCsvReportRow(results);
        });
    });
```

I have also tried it with different URLs, besides Google.com

Comment: instead of `Run` (http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Run), you should use `Run Process` (http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process). See if it works better...